# Ubuntu 18.04 fixed color and transparency in the top bar

Tags: gnome, themes, colors, transparency, top-bar

How can I prevent the Top Bar from changing color and / or transparency?

I mean, when I don't have windows that touch the edge I see it transparent and when instead there is some maximized window, or in any case that touches the edge, it turns gray.

I found where to change the color in`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file but I would like it to stay fixed whether windows are in contact with the bar or not.